# Need help identifying solder point, Is it ethernet, usb, what is it

Tags: wifi, hdmi

My end goal is to completely rewrite the flimware to create a super secure system. So what I have so far, I have a hdex0016m1 with 2 confirmed uart ports one in use and one nothing was currently going threw it, and 2 other unknown ports one I was able to access the codec chip and nothing more than watching the codec chip pass its boot test. Tested the other with nothing found coming from it. There is an 8pin on the hdmi side and I have tested it with a multi meter with no success or a sign to what it may be, I have soldered the punch outs on that side. One thing I found interesting was when I tested those pins I got nothing bug I tested some pins on the upper side of 8pin and got some interesting results 2x 3.5 pins along with 2 grounds the larger punch outs on the sides of the 8pin has no ground connection.

When I uart into the board uboot had 2 ips one is know and is used to wirelessly connect to the UI that they have included. The other is unknown.

And that's were I am at stuck

All testing has been done with a uart ttl and multimeter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMDZL.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgRDL.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpCGW.jpg

Now another thing would this be the right pin out if I was to hook a jack to it
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oorur.jpg)

Comment: the top red circled connector area in the first picture looks like a place for an RJ45 connector ... what it is used for is unknown

Comment: it might help if you explain what device you have

Comment: It's an hdex0016m1 wireless hdmi transmitter

Comment: do you know what type of a processor is being used in the device?

Comment: The codec processor is a hi 3520. It also controls the booting as well if I am reading it correctly

Comment: Flash chip set is a KH 25L12835F

Comment: Flash chip is to the left with one other one that I couldn't identify http://imgur.com/gallery/mIoL1ll

Answer (score 0):

Top one looks like an Ethernet port using a simple connector (not a magjack) with an external transformer T1. Neither has been populated so you won't measure anything at the connector pins. There's usually some capacitors and resistors as well, and I see some unpopulated passive components nearby. There could be as many as a dozen or so such parts, depending on the design.

Comment: That's what I was thinking with out an oscilloscope I dont really have a way to test if a out going signal can be achieved threw the board https://imgur.com/gallery/gPPULdg

Comment: Top view in the comment above.                                                   Bottom view here.         http://imgur.com/gallery/bwUZ0it